# Javascript and mobile browser width issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, media-queries

My goal is to prevent the js from loading on an element when the browser width is less than 500px. Basically, I don't want it to load on most mobile devices.

```
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 500px)" );
    if (mq.matches) {
       // Don't load function //
    }

    else {
       // Load function //
    }
```

It seems straightforward, and when I try it on my laptop, it works perfectly. At over 500px and the js loads. At under or equal to 500px, it doesn't load.

On my phone, however, my js media query doesn't work because the function loads. Someone suggested that it might have to do with my meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I can't seem to successfully relay the mobile browser width to javascript. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `if($(window).width() > 500)`?

Comment: I have indeed tried that. I've also tried .innerWidth and document.documentElement.clientWidth, but none of them have worked for mobile.

everything works easily for desktop, but on my Nexus 5, it never does anything.

Comment: Is it possible that your screen is bigger than 500px? What size does `$(window).width();` say that it is?

Comment: Well, my resolution is twice the size, but the width of the browser window is definitely 360. This site tells you the dimensions of your viewport size: http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/, which is what I'm basing that number off of.

Comment: Ok, then try using `min-device-width` instead of `max-width`. http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml

Comment: Awesome, I'll add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to mobile browsers you can get funky results by using `max-width: 500px` media queries, because of the high pixel densities in mobile screens. Your best bet is to use `device` media queries, e.g. `max-device-width`. So in your case it will look like this:

```
var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-device-width: 500px)");
if (mq.matches) {
   // Don't load function //
}

else {
   // Load function //
}
```